# How do you open jail cell 4 and the other jail cells during the "Save Roland" mission?

Tags: borderlands-2

I encountered this jail cell which obviously has loot behind it, but no way of interacting with the door seems to open it.  I first saw it on the "Save Roland" quest, and later on "Out of Body Experience".

[image: BorderlandsJailCell]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To open this door first **climb the nearby ladder**.

[image: Borderlands2JailCell2]

Next look for a spot where you can **jump the rail onto some pipes**.  Run down those pipes towards a somewhat hidden control room.

[image: Borderlands2JailCell3]

Finally, **switch off the green levers** to open all locked jail cells.

[image: Borderlands2JailCell4]

Comment: For the chest you only need to pull lever four. The reason for this should be obvious.

Comment: Yeah, but while you are there...

Comment: True, just wanted to point out the reasoning, and if you are trying not to waste time. You only need to pull one lever.

Answer (score -1):

I found a good video here:

Hope that helped!

Comment: Could you summarize the strategy shown in the video, so that this answer will be useful in case the video goes away?